# ¿Diferencia entre quizá, quizás y tal vez?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, diferencias-regionales

¿Cuál es la diferencia entre *quizá*, *quizás* y *tal vez*? ¿Cuándo se usa cada uno?

Es decir, ¿el uso de cada uno depende de la región, depende de lo que estás tratando de comunicar, es una cuestión de gusto, o algo más?

Answer (score 8):

Son todos sinónimos. Existe inclusive uno que es estilísticamente más poético: *acaso*.

La única diferencia de uso entre "quizás" y "quizá" es que el primero, además de ser de uso más frecuente, resulta ser la mejor opción cuando la palabra que sigue comienza con vocal. De lo contrario, se produciría el encuentro cacofónico de dos vocales:

- Quizá**s** hagamos algo juntos.
- Quizá**s** ése sea el mejor camino.
- Quizá**s** organicen una fiesta.

Cuando la palabra que sigue comienza con consonante, el uso de "quizás" o "quizá" es indistinto.

Comment: Quizás (jeje) cabría notar que *quizás* es una deformación del original *quizá*.